# Center text in StringGrid in delphi

Tags: delphi, text, alignment, center, stringgrid

I want to know how to set the text in the center of a cell in a StringGrid (Vertical AND Horizontal)... I'm using the canvas of the StringGrid.

I'm using Delphi and I want the simplest way to do it...

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use API function [DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) that has some formatting capabilities.

Simple example:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Grid: TStringGrid;
begin
  Grid := Sender as TStringGrid;
  Grid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  DrawText(Grid.Canvas.Handle, Grid.Cells[ACol, ARow],
           Length(Grid.Cells[ACol, ARow]),
           Rect, DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE);
end;
```